# Как правильно оформить код Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

В моем коде допущено две ошибки.

**Первая ошибка это:** повтор процедуры сохранения - **три раза**.

**Вторая ошибка это:** анализ на пустоту edit **именно в данном коде**.

**Помогите переделать:** Ниже приведены мои наработки, строго не судите.

Мой код:

```
procedure Tf_Main.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    fall, f1, f2, f3: TextFile;
    s: string;
    begin
    ..............
    AssignFile(fall, OpenDialog12.FileName);
         reset(fall);
     AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog12.FileName)+'\REZ_1.txt');
         rewrite(f1);
         AssignFile(f2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog12.FileName)+'\REZ_2.txt');
         rewrite(f2);
         AssignFile(f3, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog12.FileName)+'\REZ_3.txt');
         rewrite(f3);
    ............
    //работаем по строкам в файле
    while not Eof(fall) do
      begin
     //читаем строку
      ReadLn(fall, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(f1, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit2.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(f2, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit3.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(f3, S);
    .................................
```

Пытаюсь сделать по такому принципу:

```
procedure _createFile(s: string; f: TextFile; i: integer);
begin 
 if Trim(s)<>'' then begin
   AssignFile(f, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog12.FileName)+'\f'+IntToStr(i)+'.txt');
   rewrite(f);
 end;
end;

begin
  _createFile(Edit1.Text,f1, 1);
  _createFile(Edit2.Text,f2, 2);
  _createFile(Edit3.Text,f3, 2);
.....
end;
```

И вот в итоге после переделки, у меня ошибки. Знаю что переделка ужасна, из за неопытности:

```
 procedure Tf_Main.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
        var
        f: TextFile;
        s: string;
        i: integer;
    begin 
    if OpenDialog12.Execute then
    begin
         AssignFile(f, OpenDialog12.FileName);
         reset(f);
         begin
     if Trim(s)<>'' then begin
       AssignFile(f, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog12.FileName)+'\f'+IntToStr(i)+'.txt');
       rewrite(f);
     end;
     begin
///////////////////предполагаю тут что то не то делаю
          createFile(Edit1.Text,f1, 1);
          createFile(Edit2.Text,f2, 2);
          createFile(Edit3.Text,f3, 2);

    //работаем по строкам в файле
    while not Eof(f) do
      begin
     //читаем строку
      ReadLn(f, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(f1, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit2.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(f2, S);
      if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit3.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(f3, S);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure _createFile(s: string; var f: TextFile; i: integer);
```

Вам надо передавать `TextFile` в функцию `_createFile` по ссылке - обратите внимание на `var` перед `f`. Тогда в вызывающем коде у Вас будет измененная переменная, указывающая на открытый файл.

Не понял проблемы с `EditN.Text`-ом. Единственно, что `s` не используется в `_createFile`.

```
function _createFile(s: string; aDir: string; i: integer; var f: TextFile): boolean;
begin 
  result := false;
  if Trim(s) <> '' then 
  begin
    AssignFile(f, aDir + '\f' + IntToStr(i) + '.txt');
    rewrite(f);
    result := true;
  end;
end;

var
  dir: string;
  open1, open2, open3: boolean;

begin
  ...

  dir := ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog12.FileName);
  open1 := _createFile(Edit1.Text, dir, 1, f1);
  open2 := _createFile(Edit2.Text, dir, 2, f2);
  open3 := _createFile(Edit3.Text, dir, 3, f3);

  ...

    if (open1 and Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Edit1.Text), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
      writeln(f1, S);

  ...

  if open1 then
    CloseFile(f1);
  ...
```

Comment: То есть тут ошибка или ? Немного не поняла где копать.

Comment: Проблема с edit в том чтобы: не учитывать пустые Edit. То есть что бы программа сохраняла результаты только заполненных Edit. В моем случае: заполняю два из трех Edit, но программа создает три файла (третий пустой). Как это можно сделать в данном коде ?

Comment: Очень помогли Igor. Разобралась, теперь все заработало. Теперь поняла, сам принцип. И еще в open1 := тоже разобралась. Без вас никак бы. Информации много но когда показывают на пальцах то это намного проще.

Comment: @Татьяна Рад, что дело прояснилось. Успехов.

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не так

```
if Edit1.Text <> '' then
_createFile(Edit1.Text, dir, 1, f1);
```